# Alternatives to cpp-netlib to do asynchronous http requests in C++

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, asihttprequest, cpp-netlib

I spent half of the day today unsuccessfully trying to install [cpp-netlib](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib) on Mac OS X (the goal is to implement asynchronous http requests in C++). When I do 'make' to build and run the tests, I have lots of "no matching constructor" errors coming from Boost. Having read [this](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/issues/123), I tried installing different versions of Boost (1.49, 1.50, 1.51), but that didn't help. So I'm at the point of thinking of alternatives to cpp-netlib. One possibility is to use Boost.Asio directly, but it would have been great to use something like cpp-netlib as it is much easier to use once it's installed. Any alternatives to cpp-netlib which come to mind? Or any other way I should try to make cpp-netlib pass the tests? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Boost::Asio isn't that hard once you get used to it, give it a go.
Read the examples, not only the ones that you are interested in directly, helped me much.

Comment: @jt234 cpp-netlib is at a higher level than Boost ASIO, and probably _uses_ ASIO as it's goal is to be a part of Boost.

Comment: Arman, could you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) together with the errors, then maybe we can help you with those instead? Otherwise this question will probably be closed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I actually decided to stick with cpp-netlib. Thanks for your help!